# Laravel 4: How to pass a div id to View::make()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my codes:

routes.php

```
Route::get('menu', function()
{
    return View::make('display_food');
});
```

menu.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function linkPage()
{
  location.href = "menu";
}
</script>

......
......

<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="linkPage()">Menu</button>
```

I wanted to pass a div id "#link_menu" to the url so that when it loads, it is display like this "http://www.abc.com/food_cms/system/public/menu#link_menu" which can make the page jump to the section i want. However, I have tried with

```
Route::get('menu', function()
    {
        return View::make('display_food')->with('#link_menu');
    });
```

And

```
Route::get('menu', function()
{
    return View::make('display_food',compact('#link_menu'));
});
```

And this

```
Route::get('menu', function()
{
    return View::make('display_food')->with(compact('#link_menu'));
});
```

But none of them are working. The url is still display in "http://www.abc.com/food_cms/system/public/menu" without "#link_menu". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to have your `location.href` go to an anchor, first:

```
 window.location = "#anchor";
```

Just before the content that you want to jump to, have a named anchor tag, such as this:

```
 <a id="anchor"></a><h1>my content</h1>
```

Inside your view, you will want something similar to this, so you can specify the anchor that you want to jump to from within your controller/router:

```
<head>
<title>This page will go straight to the anchor I specify...</title>
@if (isset($jump_to))
<script>
function window.onload() {
    window.location = "#{{$jump_to}}"
}
</script>
@endif
</head><body>
<p>lot's of content...</p>
<p>lot's of content...</p>
<p>lot's of content...</p>
[...]
<a id="anchor"></a><h1>my content</h1>
</body>
```

Then with your route, you specify that the view with a particular $jump_to variable, which specifies where you will be thrown to.

```
Route::get('menu/{id}', function($menu_id)
{
    return View::make('display_food')->with('jump_to' => $menu_id);
});
```

If $jump_to is specified, the javascript will be added, and the browser will jump down to the anchor tag that you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You have this `url`:

```
http://www.abc.com/food_cms/system/public/menu#link_menu
```

Actually, the part after `#` is not submitted to the server, you need to pass using a query string like:

```
http://www.abc.com/food_cms/system/public/menu?menuId=link_menu
//location.href = "menu?menuId=link_menu";
```

So you can get it using:

```
$menuId = Inpput::get('menuId');
```

You may also use this:

```
Route::get('menu/{id}', function($menu_id)
{
    return View::make('display_food', compact('menu_id'));
});
```

To make it work you may construct your `url` like this:

```
http://www.abc.com/food_cms/system/public/menu/ink_menu
//location.href = "menu/link_menu";
```

In your `view` you may use it as `$menu_id` and it'll contain `ink_menu` without the `#` so concatenate it before you use it.